# How update vim to 8.0 version in OSX?

Tags: vim

The current vim i'm using is 7.3 version.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 14 2016 16:06:49)
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

I tried to update vim to 8.0 by the command:

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
```

However, it doesn't work. It's still vim 7.3.

Comment: Download the latest MacVim release.

Comment: Actually, this is correct to build vim for console; `make install` to install it. Nice to know how easy it is without any package managers.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You may have compiled vim, but the `vim` that's first in your path is still the system vim. You can show that using:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

You can either call your compiled vim directly (probably in a folder called `dist` or `bin`), or put it in a place that is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` variable. The easiest way to get an up-to-date vim on OS X is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install vim --with-override-system-vi
```

Comment: Will that install vim 8.0? (I.e., does Homebrew know about the latest version yet)?

Comment: Homebrew is usually very up-to-date, so yes, you'll get vim 8 (I have it too).

Comment: I tried this method, and installed vim 8.0 successfully. However, the vim is in still 7.3 version. So I set an alias to vim 8.0 in that folder.

Comment: Put /usr/local/bin first in your path.  And brew is on it's 4th or 5th minor version update of vim 8 (8.0.0019 as of just a few days ago).

Comment: I've just tried the `brew install vim --override-system-vim` command but it updated vim to the version 7.4, not 8

Comment: This updates the command `vim` on my mac and not `vi`. To point `vi` to the latest version I had to add `alias vi="vim"` to my bash configuration `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`.

Comment: `Warning: vim: this formula has no --override-system-vim option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: This is supposed to be: `brew install vim --override-system-vi` (no `m` at the end).

Comment: Looks like it's now `brew install vim --with-override-system-vi`

Comment: when I run ```vim``` in the command line version 7.3 is shown. However, when I run ```brew upgrade vim``` I get ```Error: vim 8.0.0728_1 already installed``` How do I switch to version 8?

Comment: It didn't override the `/usr/bin/vim` in my case, perhaps I should use `sudo`. Instead I used `sudo ln /usr/local/Cellar/vim/<myVimVersion>/bin/vim` /usr/bin/vim`

Comment: @Steven Angular I had the same problem. Re-opening the console solved this.

Comment: @GerardoZinno Had the same issue, but realised that it was an issue with home brew (I have an old version, which I discovered with brew -v). See this thread on home brew support for how to fix this: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-upgrade-brew-stuck-on-0-9-9/33

Comment: Using the homebrew formula above, I now have vim 8.0 at `/usr/local/bin/vim` and vim 7.3 at `/usr/bin/vim`. Any recommendations for how to rearrange my path? Or should I delete `/usr/bin/vim` and replace it with a symlink?

Comment: When you start vim, is the correct Vim started? If yes, leave it be, you should not delete the system Vim. If no, adjust your path e.g. by putting `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` in your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, or similar.

Comment: worked without using --with-override-system-vi as it is an invalid option.

Answer (score 14):

Trying

```
brew install vim --override-system-vim
```

didn't work for me either.

Upgrade Homebrew to latest version and then use

```
brew upgrade vim
```

Comment: You don't need to upgrade Homebrew, it'll update itself automatically

Answer (score 8):

vim --version

`$ brew install vim --with-override-system-vi`

Sounds dumb but *most importantly* close the terminal and then reopen it to see the new version of vim `$ vim --version`.

Comment: God bless the sounds dumb addition, I was dumb

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the final step for installing from source after running `make`:

```
sudo make install
```

That should install it to your path.